# Keep user location center in Google Maps - Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I have implemented Google maps in to a swift project and using locationManager to track and currently print out the users location.

I am also changing the camera position as the user moves around however this seems a bit jerky as the map moves then the blue dot (user location) moves.

Is there a way to keep the user location centered at all times and just have the map move?

Comment: You just need to zoom out a little bit try span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.05, longitudeDelta: 0.05)

Answer (score 0):

you can easily enable

```
mapView.myLocationEnabled = true
```

and see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41012745/2739657) for more info to camera updating -> as it shows how to update camera with 2 positions or center a location

Answer (score 0):

Plaese, see if [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40951345/zoom-into-current-users-location-on-mapview-without-restricting-scrolling/40951506?noredirect=1#comment69169295_40951506) answer helps you. The user location is centered all the time in the example code. There is no camera adustment though, but that shouldn't make a difference.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score -1):

```
let center = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: location.coordinate.latitude, longitude: location.coordinate.longitude)        
let region = MKCoordinateRegion(center: center, span: MKCoordinateSpan(latitudeDelta: 0.01, longitudeDelta: 0.01))
self.map.setRegion(region, animated: true)
```