# Swift Google Maps Center on Marker Click

Tags: swift

I am trying to center the Google map on the marker and zoom when the user taps a marker.  I am able to do this in Android using a the click delegate, but I can't find a way to do this in Swift.

Does anyone have any hints or advice to solve this issue?

Answer (score 5):

You have to conform the GMSMapViewDelegate protocol , then you have the func below:

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {

    //you can handle zooming and camera update here 

}
```

you can update the camera by creating bound for more than one position like : ( also you can give a padding to the bound)

```
let bounds = GMSCoordinateBounds(coordinate: self.userLocation!.coordinate, coordinate: marker.position)
self.mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(GMSCameraUpdate.fitBounds(bounds, withPadding: 120.0))
```

and also you can update the camera position with one position with a zoom level like :

```
self.mapView?.camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithTarget(marker.position, zoom: 9.0)
```

Answer (score 1):

in swift4 for click on Marker:

```
 func mapView(_ mapView: GMSMapView, didTap marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
     // your code.
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I will answer your question in parts:

**Center the Google Map on the marker:**

```
let camera = GMSCameraPosition.cameraWithLatitude(lat, longitude: long, zoom: 8.0)
self.mapView.camera = camera
```

*where lat, long are the coordinates of place where you put your marker.*

**Zoom when the user taps a marker:**

```
func mapView(mapView: GMSMapView, didTapMarker marker: GMSMarker) -> Bool {
    let update = GMSCameraUpdate.zoomBy(2)
    mapView.animateWithCameraUpdate(update)
}
```

Also, make sure your class conforms to `GMSMapViewDelegate`.