# Zoom into current user's location on MapView without restricting scrolling?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm using the following code to zoom into my user's current location on a MapView. It works great, however I still want to allow my users to be able to scroll outside of the set region as well (e.g. so that they can see other users on the map). Right now, if my user scrolls outside of the set region, the MapView reverts the user back inside of the set region. How can I execute the below code (zooming into the user's location) while still allowing them to scroll outside of the set region?

**MapViewController.m**

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{

    MKCoordinateRegion region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(userLocation.coordinate, 1300, 1300);
    [self.mapView setRegion:[self.mapView regionThatFits:region] animated:YES];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote a short an easy app that will show the user location and also keeps track of the user location. The app will focus on the user location and will keep the user location centered as long as you don't scroll the map view.

As soon as you start scrolling the map view moves away from the user location and stays that way, since the map view is not automatically moving back. To enable you to get back to the user location, I added a button called "focus" that centers the map view back to the user location and makes the map again focus on the user location until you start scrolling away again.

The app is actually quite simple, it uses the two properties in MKMapView:

```
var showUserLocation: Bool {get set}
var userTrackingMode: MKUserTrackingMode {get set}
```

You can, of course, zoom further in to the user location by setting the region, but that is easily done with the setRegion(_:animated:).

You can find the code on Github [here](https://github.com/MacUserT/User-Location) and download it to see how it works. You can easily test this with the simulator.

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Ohhh that makes sense. That said, if I move the code to viewWillAppear, userLocation is now undefined? How should I go about redefining it in viewWillAppear (as I'm now terminating that void method)?

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by the fact that the user location is undefined?

Comment: Please, look at my addition at the end. Does that answer your question?

Comment: When I get rid of this line: (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
 and move MKCoordinateRegion to viewDidAppear, XCode throws me an error that says "use of undeclared identifier userLocation". So how would I change the MKCoordinateRegion line to get rid of this error?

Comment: Yes, I understand. I will write you some alternative code tomorrow. Now it is quite late in Europe.

Comment: Please do!! Thank you so much!

Comment: A changed the answer. Please, have a look at the code and let me know if this works for you.

Comment: Going to give it a try this afternoon! If I'm not using swift though, will that method still work?

Comment: Yes, you can translate it to Objective-C without any problem.